# How to make usestate back to default value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a usestate lik this

```
const [currentApp, setCurrentApp] = useState({})
```

the output of `currentApp` is

```
{
    activity_name_id: ["1"]
    ceo_birthday: "1400-03-07"
    ceo_gender: "0"
    ceo_id_code: "2233323655666666555"
    ceo_photo: "/pic_user/userPic_1624200842.jpg"
    ceo_photo_id: "51"
    charity_id: "14"
    charity_verified: "0"
    website: null
    ....
}
```

the list depends on how many field is filled and I want to set all of that to `'-'` I used this code but not working

```
const newCurrentApp = Object.keys(currentApp).reduce((acc, field) => {
    acc[field] = ""
    return acc
}, {})
```

Comment: Please provide some sample input and expected output.

Comment: You want to set all of what to `'-'` ?

Comment: @iota  I add that

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: @PixAff yes I added the output of `currentApp`

Comment: it is still not clear, what you are trying to achieve. If you want to set your `currentApp` to something you would need to `setCurrentApp(*your code here*)`

Comment: @PixAff I want to set all of the `currentApp` to `'-'`

Comment: Then you would `setCurrentApp('-')`

Answer (score 0):

To set all the values of the object to `'-'`, you can directly loop over the keys without `reduce` and modify the object.

```js
const currentApp = {
    activity_name_id: ["1"],
    ceo_birthday: "1400-03-07",
    ceo_gender: "0",
    ceo_id_code: "2233323655666666555",
    ceo_photo: "/pic_user/userPic_1624200842.jpg",
    ceo_photo_id: "51",
    charity_id: "14",
    charity_verified: "0",
    website: null
    // ...
};
Object.keys(currentApp).forEach(k => currentApp[k] = '-');
console.log(currentApp);
```